# Partial derivative involving Kronecker product

Tags: partial-derivative, kronecker-product

I have the following question:

For the function

$f=\|XY^\top-A(I\otimes X)Z^\top\|_{F}^{2}$

where $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product, and $\|\cdot\|_{F}$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

What is the result of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}\def\v{{\rm vec}}\def\d{{\rm diag}}\def\D{{\rm Diag}}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{{\partial}}\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}\def\z{{\rm size}}$For
typing convenience, define the following matrix variables
$$\eqalign{
R &= XY^T-A(I_p\otimes X)Z^T \\
B &= A^TRZ \\
}$$
and use $e_k$ to denote the $k^{th}$ column of the identity matrix $I_p\,$ in order to define the block matrices
$$\eqalign{
&M_k = e_k\otimes I_m \\
&N_k = e_k\otimes I_n \\
}$$
and the matrix sum
$$\eqalign{
&S = \sum_{k=1}^p\;M_k^TBN_k\\
}$$

Let's also assign concrete dimensions to all of the matrices involved
$$\eqalign{
m,n &= \z(X) = \z(S) \\
q,n &= \z(Y) \\
m,mp &= \z(A) \\
p,p &= \z(I_p),\quad\z(e_k) = p,1 \\
q,np &= \z(Z) \\
m,q &= \z(R) \\
mp,np &= \z(B) \\
mp,m &= \z(M_k) \\
np,n &= \z(N_k) \\
}$$
One final bit of notation is to use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
S:X &= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n\;S_{ij} X_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(S^TX) \\
X:X &= \big\|X\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Now write the objective using the above notation. Then calculate its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
f &= R:R \\
df &= 2R:dR \\
 &= 2R:\big(dX\,Y^T - A(I_p\otimes dX)Z^T\big) \\
 &= 2RY:dX - 2A^TRZ:(I_p\otimes dX) \\
 &= 2RY:dX - 2B:(I_p\otimes dX) \\
 &= 2(RY-S):dX \\
\grad{f}{X} &= 2(RY-S) \\\\
}$$

---

The following identity was utilized above
$$\eqalign{
S:dX &= \sum_{k=1}^p\;
  \left(e_k^T\otimes I_m\right)B\left(e_k\otimes I_n\right):dX \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^p\;
B:\left(e_k\otimes I_m\right)(I_\o\otimes dX)\left(e_k^T\otimes I_n\right) \\
  &= \sum_{k=1}^p\;B:\big(e_ke_k^T\big)\otimes\big(dX\big) \\
  &= B:I_p\otimes dX \\
}$$